# checkboxes getting checked in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am trying to check a checkbox and keep its state to checked until it gets unchecked but as soon as I close the dialog containing the checkboxes and come back to it, all the checkboxes are checked instead of the selected one. I have tried the following way

```
private void saveCheckboxState(int index1, int index2, boolean isChecked)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("checkbox" + index1 + index2, isChecked);
    editor.apply();
}

private boolean getCheckboxState(int index1, int index2)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager. getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    return prefs.getBoolean("checkbox" + index1 + index2, false);
}


boolean checkbox_success;
  case R.id.menu_checkboxes:
     Dialog s_dialog = new Dialog(this);
     s_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.s_dialog);
     checkbox_layout = s_dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_layout);
                
     layoutParams.setMargins(20,20,20,20);

     s_dialog.show();
     title = s_dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
     title.setText("select option ");
     
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       
                
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setId(groupIndex);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                 checkbox_success = true;
                 
                 boolean success = db.update(String.valueOf(items.getId())
                  );
                                   
                
            }
          
       });                                   
          checkbox_layout.addView(checkBox);
    }
  }
```

Is there any way I can get it to check only the selected items? Thanks for help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239099/discussion-on-question-by-m-umer-checkboxes-getting-checked-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

[image]> This is what I suggest you do.
Create an Int variable and assign a value == 1 to it when checkBox is Checked, so when Dialog is recreated/created you check if isChecked == 0 or 1 and change the status of the checkBox based on the result, view the code below.

```
var isChecked: Int = 0
Dialog.....//isCreated
if(isChecked == 1)
   //set checkBox isChecked = true
else //set checkBox isChecked = false
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more because it is confusing how would it save the position of checked box in the database?

Comment: When the DialogBox shows and checkBox isCheck, assign a value to your Int variable =1.

Comment: If you could add some code in your answer, it would be really helpful.

Comment: When the DialogBox shows and checkBox isCheck, assign a value to your Int variable =1. So when next the dialog shows/created use the above conditional statement to check if your isChecked variable is == 1 using the above code. If isChecked == 1 set the checkBox to checked by default else if isChecked variable is == 0 set the checkBox to unchecked

Comment: "When the DialogBox shows and checkBox isCheck" that is my problem. the checkbox does not stay checked or all of them get checked. This is what I am trying to accomplish above, when the dialog show up, I want my only my selected box to be checked.

Comment: Check the image above.

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
boolean checked = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
.getBoolean("checkBox1", false);
 checkBox1.setChecked(checked);
```

> Try this method using sharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

Will give an example how to save checkbox states in shared preferences and to read them back.

Code is only for one loop.

You have to realise that if you have two loops you should use two indexes to store a state.

```
private void saveCheckboxState(int index, boolean isChecked)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("checkbox" + index, isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean getCheckboxState(int index)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager. getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    return prefs.getBoolean("checkbox" + index, false);
}
```

At building your dialog call getCheckboxState().
Call saveCheckboxState() in the on change handler.

For two loops you only have to adapt the functions with another index.
For instance it would become `private void saveCheckboxState(int index1,`int index2,  boolean isChecked)` then.

I suggest you code the functions for two indexes and post your code here.

Comment: I posted the code above but unfortunately the result is not changing.

Comment: `getCheckboxState(groupIndex,trackIndex);` You should use the return value: `checkBox.setSelected(getCheckboxState(groupIndex,trackIndex));`

Comment: `saveCheckboxState(finalGroupIndex, finalTrackIndex,checkbox_success);` You should log and or Toast those two positions to see if they are the rigth one. I would rather see something like `saveCheckboxState(groupIndex, trackIndex,isChecked);` Where trackindex =  buttonView.getId(); But then  checkBox.setId(groupIndex); should be  checkBox.setId(trackIndex); Well you need two indexes for every box. You could also try  checkBox.setId(groupIndex + "-" + trackIndex); Then you have both indexes in one.
     
     `

Comment: Just change the functions a little to handle the combined index. And... first look/test if the rigth indexes are toasted when a checkbox is clicked.

Comment: And i wonder why you did not first test my code with only one loop. You could have stoppped the first loop after on iteration.

Comment: "You should log and or Toast those two positions to see if they are the rigth one." The `finalGroupIndex` is returning the correct value while `finalTrackIndex` is always returning 0.

Comment: I gave you enough hints by now to solve this double indexes problem. Solve it first. All starts with using the right indexes.

Comment: I set id to both indexes `checkBox.setId(trackIndex + groupIndex);` but it still works the same as before.

Comment: Wel you realize that checkBox.setId(1 + 2); would be the same as checkBox.setId(2+1); or checkBox.setId(3+0); ? I already told you that before and even gave you a solution. You should log much more such values. Than you see what happens.

Comment: the log values of trackIndex are always 0 and for groupIndex are `0 1 2 3 4`. if you combine the ids as  `checkBox.setId(trackIndex + groupIndex);` are `00 01 02 03 04`.

Comment: If the track index is always 0 then you should first solve that problem. I told you to use logs and toasts to solve that problem. You first should get both index values back . Also you could tell how many groups and tracks you use.

Comment: `if you combine the ids as checkBox.setId(trackIndex + groupIndex); are 00 01 02 03 04.`Well sorry i do not believe that. They are just added as setId() takes an integer. Log the value of getId() to see.

Comment: I have come up with the index solution. I kept it functionality and it is working fine as well. You can see it above.

Comment: I will give you a last hint. At creating the checkboxes use `checkBox.setId((trackIndex *100 )+ groupIndex);` And in the onCheckChangeListener use `int id =  buttonView.getId();                           int index1 = id / 100;
                            int index2 = id % 100;
 ` . Toast both values! to see. And i see nothing above and only one loop.